# FAR fails to execute programs from symlinked directories

Tags: windows-7, far-manager

I am really stuck with the following problem.

[FAR](http://www.farmanager.com/index.php?l=en) as well as other programs like [Executor](http://www.executor.dk/) cannot execute programs with following symptom:

[image: FAR showing error when I press Enter]

Additional information:

- `C:\Programs\Eclipse` is junction for `C:\Programs\Eclipse (32bit)`
- Programs from ordinary directories are executed OK. So the problem really occurs only in juncted current path.
- If I execute Eclipse using full path from command line (`C:\Programs\Eclipse\eclipse.exe`) it works.
- If I execute Eclipse via <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> dialog and full path (`C:\Programs\Eclipse\eclipse.exe`) it works.
- If I execute Eclipse from `cmd.exe` (`cd C:\Programs\Eclipse && eclipse.exe`) it works.
- The same problem happens with other juncted directories, e.g. `C:\Programs\WinRAR → C:\Programs\WinRAR (32 bit)`.
- From juncted directory other programs in `%PATH%` are not executed, e.g. `start` reports that program was not found.

It seems like I haven't changed anything fundamental on PC for last time. Checked for viruses. What it can be? Perhaps recent Windows update has introduced this problem?

Comment: Eclipse 32bit run in Far Manager, version 2.0 (build 981) x86 ... but I not run `Executor`

Comment: Replace junctions with symlinks and see if it works.

Comment: Sorry, wanted to say that the problem is not in FAR or Eclipse. The problem is in Windows OS basically the way the execution takes places. I have found the problem after few midnight hours...

Comment: The problem seems to be solved in Far 3, check [here](http://bugs.farmanager.com/view.php?id=2367).

Answer (score 1):

The problem was really difficult to catch. Most of internet points to the [problem with registry](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2688326#LetMeFixItMyselfAlways) but after I have created a new user with clean profile the problem was still there.

I have analysed installed updates:

- [Update for Microsoft Windows (KB2729094)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2729094) from 01/06/2013
- [Update for Microsoft Windows (KB2670838)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2670838) from 01/06/2013
- Windows Internet Explorer 10.

Earlier updates (before 16/05/2013) seemed to be not relevant, as system was working OK at that period. First two updates also seems to have no impact on core (they are too specific), so I have uninstalled IE 10 (rolling back to IE 9). And after reboot everything start working again! Hooray!

My regards to MS IE.